# Can't set up Maven on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, bash, maven, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Mac OSX and I'm running Yosemite. I am trying to set up Maven using [this official guide](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) in order to set up a Google Cloud Messaging Backend. Here's what I did:

> 1) Downloaded Maven zip (version: apache-maven-3.3.9) and Unzipped it
>
> 2) As the guide says, I need to add the bin directory to my PATH variable. So I did the following in my terminal

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The terminal didn't return any response. However when I checked to see if Maven got installed using:

> mvn -version

I get a message saying:

> -bash: mvn: command not found

What am I doing wrong? Did I follow the steps properly to set up Maven?

**EDIT:**

**MVN Bin Directory path is:**

> /Users/Earthling/Documents/Projects/MobiProject/apache-maven-3.3.9

Comment: do `echo $PATH` and check your `maven bin` directory location

Comment: Does `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn -version` work?

Comment: @SajanChandran Edited the response

Comment: @JoaoMorais It doesn't give any error response. The shell jumps to a new line with no response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$PATH` is what point where your programs are, because of that you change it in order to find `mvn`. Actually you are pointing `$PATH` to `$M2_HOME/bin`.

You need to update `$M2_HOME` to one directory level before mvn bin and before update `$PATH`.

If this is your mvn home:

```
/Users/Earthling/Documents/Projects/MobiProject/apache-maven-3.3.9
```

you should use this env vars:

```
export M2_HOME="/Users/Earthling/Documents/Projects/MobiProject/apache-maven-3.3.9"
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

You can also edit your `~/.profile` in order to include these lines, so you don't need to type these `exports` whenever you open your terminal.

Comment: Thanks man! This was exactly what I was doing and you posted the answer as well. This worked

Comment: Simplest is to use only `$PATH` entry to the location of Maven and nothing else...

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the manual steps here and still couldn't get it to work. Then I realized I can easily install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), much more convenient:

```
brew install maven
```

that's all you need to install maven for mac!

Answer (score 0):

Do

`export M2_HOME=/Users/Earthling/Documents/Projects/MobiProject/apache-maven-3.3.9`

Comment: Okay the Shell jumped to a new line without any error response. But when I check the mvn version with mvn -version I get the same error: "-bash: mvn: command not found
"

Comment: Can you explain? I am new to Mac osx so Im not quite familiar with all the keywords